# How to get closest item in array to the specified index that makes a function return true (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make it so if I have an array of objects, and I have the `index` of an object that does not make a function return true, how can I find the `object` closest to `index` that does make the function return true?

The object:

```js
[
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: true,
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: false,
        type: 'date'
    },
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: true,
        type: 'number'
    },
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: false,
        type: 'member'
    },
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: true,
        type: 'message'
    },
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: false,
        type: 'choices',
        choices: ['something', 'something-else']
    },
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: true,
        type: 'emoji'
    },
    {
        name: 'something',
        required: false,
        type: 'role'
    }
]
```

The function:

```js
let function = (arg) => this.validateType(arg.type, content);
// content is "something" if that matters
```

Thanks.

Comment: give some examples

Comment: Iterate the indexes around the supplied index until the function returns true or you reach both ends of the array

Comment: I just added examples.

Comment: Providing inputs with expected results would be helpful. One edge case to consider would be if you are looking for an index of 3 (assume this one returns false), and index of 2 and 4 both returns true from your test, which index do you want to return  (2 or 4)?

Comment: Dependent on the data and the function, you may be able to optimise that, for example by using bisection.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I got something to work.